# Template strings use pattern matching

Tags: typescript

```
type Foo<Str extends string, Search extends string> = Str extends `${infer _R1}${Search}${infer _R2}` ? `${_R1}` : false

type Res1 = Foo<'linbudu', 'lin'> // ""
```

Please tell me why _R1 is not a string "l" but a "", and how to understand what happened to ${Search} in the middle of infer?

Comment: Why do you consider the second one correct?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know why _R1 is a "", and what does ${Search} mean here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed types for better understanding. Here is the [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgOwCYAkIEMkB4AqEAewUBwEyAzlOcAE6IDmANFAMoCuARi7Q8YWUkrU6CegD4oAXih5CfUhSgADACQBvRADMINKGkwBfdey49RRtcIYGlUAPzL1+pDagAuKJvQAbchABQ-qCQUABKAIxSsIioGNgA5N6IHGxIbPHMiYjxEgD0uVAARIVB4NChAExR8MjOWFkIKWkZUPHpeQWFSY0lweUAzNUxdQ1N6ZkA1jlQ+Z4+fkA).

This type searches for `SubString` in `Text`. If it finds a substring it returns all characters before its first occurance. It returns `false` if substring is not found.

So `Head` (yours `_R1`) is the inferrence of string before the first occurance of `SubString` in `Text`. And `SubString` (yours `Search`) is a substring the type searches in `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Foo type, the Str parameter is expected to be a string, and the Search parameter is a substring that is searched for in Str.

When you use ${infer _R1}${infer _R2}${infer _R3} in the conditional type, you are telling TypeScript to split Str into three parts and store them in the variables _R1, _R2, and _R3.

In the case of Res2 = Foo<'linbudu', 'lin'>, _R1 will be 'l', _R2 will be 'inbu', and _R3 will be 'du'.

However, since you only want to return the first character of Str if Search is found in Str, you only need to use the first part of the split string, which is stored in _R1. This is why you return ${_R1} in the true branch of the conditional type.

The reason _R1 is not a string "l" but a "" when Search is not found in Str is because the conditional type only returns a string if the condition is true. In the case where Search is not found in Str, the condition is false, and the type of the expression ${_R1} is "", which is the empty string.

So, to understand what happened to ${Search} in the middle of the infer, you need to know that ${infer ...} is a syntax in TypeScript that allows you to capture parts of a string and use them in a type. In this case, you're using it to split Str into three parts, but you're not doing anything with ${Search} specifically.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).